# Exception while creating a socket

Tags: c++, glibmm

I am using glibmm v2.42 on linux.

I want to create a client / server using native linux socket.

When trying to create a socket, an exception is always thrown with code 15 (not supported).

On the code below I looped over socket family enum, type enum and protocol enum but it always fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm.h>
#include <giomm.h>

int main(){
  Glib::init();
  Gio::init();

  std::vector<Gio::SocketFamily> fams = {Gio::SOCKET_FAMILY_UNIX , Gio::SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV4 , Gio::SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV6};
  std::vector<Gio::SocketType> types = {Gio::SOCKET_TYPE_STREAM, Gio::SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM, Gio::SOCKET_TYPE_SEQPACKET };
  std::vector<Gio::SocketProtocol> protocols = {Gio::SOCKET_PROTOCOL_DEFAULT , Gio::SOCKET_PROTOCOL_TCP, Gio::SOCKET_PROTOCOL_UDP, Gio::SOCKET_PROTOCOL_SCTP };
   Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Cancellable> cancellable = Gio::Cancellable::create();

 for(int i = 0; i  < fams.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < types.size(); j++){
        for(int k= 0; k < protocols.size(); k++){

            Gio::SocketFamily fam = fams[i];
            Gio::SocketType type= types[j];
            Gio::SocketProtocol protocol = protocols[k];

            try {
               Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Socket> socket = Gio::Socket::create(fam , type, protocol , cancellable);
            } catch(const Gio::Error& e){
                std::cout << e.code() << std::endl;
            }
        }
     }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Any ideas ?
Does anyone have a working example of client/server with native linux socket using glibmm ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : In the code I removed the XXX and wrote the loops. This code returns 15 for all parameters configurations

Comment: You should not use the XXX values in MVCE. If the combination of the flags are wrong, noone would ever be able to tell you that that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: The answer to your problem is ... YYY ^^

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can help.

Comment: My apologizes but I am not allowed to copy paste my full example. However I removed the XXX of the code and show directely the loops over the input parameters ^^